# Changing the displayed value of an <option> element's text without modifying the element itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<select>` element with a recursively generated list of options, like this:

[image: SelectElement]

It looks great when being displayed on the page like that, but I was wondering if there is a way to change the text value that gets displayed on the main `<select>` element. If I select "CategoryE" for example, the displayed text looks like this:

[image: CategoryESelected]

Which is logically expected, but as you can see, the selected text retains its leading whitespace and looks messy. I'm trying to go for a `trim()` effect that only changes the displayed value when it's selected, but retains that whitespace in the actual `<option>` list so you can still see how the category relates to the others in the option tree.

This code unfortunately changes both:

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    var selected = $(this).children(":selected");
    var text = $(selected).text().trim();
    $(selected).html(text);
});
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I want without saving and restoring the leading whitespace, or do I have to resort to doing that?

## Edit

As requested, this is the server-side (PHP) function that generates the options:

```
function listOptions($root, $prefix, $isRoot) {
    $list = "";
    if($isRoot) {
        $list .= "<option value=\"" . $root["id"] . "\">"
            . $prefix . $root["name"] . "</option>";
        $list .= listOptions($root["children"], $prefix . "&nbsp;&nbsp;", false);
    } else {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($root); $i++) {
            $curr = $root[$i];
            $list .= "<option value=\"" . $curr["id"] . "\">"
                . $prefix . $curr["name"] . "</option>";

            $children = $curr["children"];
            if(count($children) > 0) {
                $list .= listOptions($children, $prefix . "&nbsp;&nbsp;", false);
            }
        }
    }

    return $list;
}
```

Function call looks like:

```
<select ...>
    <?php echo listOptions($cats, "", true); ?>
</select>
```

Generated HTML looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your HTML code too? A working example might be easier to look at.

Comment: @BlackPearl added code at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0):

This solution is hacky and likely a cross-browser liability,  but not exactly sure what alternatives you really have.

You could wrap the `<select>` in a container and give it a sibling `<span>`.

That span could cover the selected text so that it doesn't show. To maintain the select functionality, you'd just have to apply `pointer-events: none` so that the mouse behaves as if the `<span>` isn't there.

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var $selected = $(this).children(":selected");
  var text = $selected.text().trim();
  $(this).siblings("span").text(text);
});
```

```css
.container { 
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block; 
}

.container > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 2px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 22px);
}

select, span { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span>One</span>
  <select>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;Two</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```